# Conditional Distribution in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, conditional-probability

In a logistic regression, given that  $\pi_i=Pr(Y_i=1|X_i=x_i)=\dfrac{\text{exp}(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)}{1+\text{exp}(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)}$, is it correct to say that logistic regression assumes that the conditional distribution $f(Y|X) \sim  Logistic$?

Comment: The assumed distribution in logistic regression is **binomial**. $f(Y_i|X_i = x_i) \sim B(1, \pi_i(x_i))$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does the logistic distribution only apply to the errors then? It just seems intuitive that because we estimate probabilities using a logistic function, this follows from the conditional being logistically distributed- do you see where I am coming from?

Comment: The logistic distribution doesn't have much to do with logistic regression - except that the link function is the same as the CDF for $\mu=0, s=1$ (wikipedia notation)

Comment: @AlexR Actually, there is a connection to the logistic distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b You're right, cf. [Latent variable interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Latent_variable_interpretation)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to flesh out some of the comments to this post into an answer (with thanks to [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b) and [AlexR](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/78492/alexr) for their excellent comments).  The first thing to note is that the response variable in a logistic regression is binary, with allowable values $y_i = 0,1$, so any distribution that does not accord with that support is incorrect.  The distribution for the response variable in a logistic regression is Bernoulli, with a logistic mean.

> **Response distribution:** The response distribution for a logistic regression is:
>
> $$Y_i | \mathbf{x} \sim \text{Bern}(\pi(x_i)) \quad \quad \quad \pi(x_i) = \frac{\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)}{1 + \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)}.$$
>
> The function $\pi$ is a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) of an affine transformation of the argument value $x_i$.

The logistic regression model can be represented using various (equivalent) model forms that yield the above response distribution.  One of these model formulations uses a pseudo-error term with a standard [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).  Taking $\varepsilon_i \sim \text{Logistic}(0, 1)$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i > 0) = 1- F_{\varepsilon_i}(0) 
&= 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)}{1 + \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)} \\[8pt]
&= \pi(x_i). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Since this is the probability of a positive response outcome in the above distribution, we can formulate the logistic regression model in a way that is similar to a standard linear regression model, but with a pseudo-error term that is only used to classify the response into two categories:

$$Y_i = \mathbb{I}(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i > 0) \quad \quad \quad \varepsilon_1, ..., \varepsilon_n | \mathbf{x} \sim \text{IID Logistic}(0, 1).$$