Is there an "observation noise" formulation for logistic regression?
In formulating linear regression as the solution to maximum likelihood problem, we need the assumption that the data $X$ and label $Y$ are related by
$$Y = w^TX + \epsilon$$
where $\epsilon$ is a Gaussian observational noise.
Written this way, we can define the conditional probability $\Pr[Y = y|X = x]$ as a Gaussian with mean $w^Tx$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Is there a way to do the same for logistic regression? I find that in the MLE formulation of logistic regression, we directly assume $\Pr[Y = y|X = x]$ is the logistic function, with no observation noise mentioned.

Wikipedia gives something related for probit regression. If you change the Gaussian to a logistic distribution, you have logistic regression. Is that what you are looking for? $//$ I've done simulations where I introduce errors to 0/1 data by adding 1 and then modding by 2, something like y_correct <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5); y_corrupt <- (y_correct + rbinom(1000, 1, 0.1)) %% 2.

There's the latent variable version

The latent variable approach motivates probit regression, which is not unlike logistic regression, but I think the probit link can yield different estimates of the coefficients, which in turn have different coefficients.  One might be forgiven for thinking that probit regression is then not logistic regression.

There's a latent variable version of logistic regression with continuous logistic error term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#As_a_latent-variable_model

One possible answer is Ben's at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353231/conditional-distribution-in-logistic-regression/353518#353518

Gaussian random variables have the property that if $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, then $X + \mu \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2$).  Hence, we can write $Y = X w^T + \varepsilon$ and this is equivalent to writing $Y \mid X \sim N(X w^T, \sigma^2)$.
Binomial random variables do not have the same sort of property, hence they can't be written with additive noise.  However, we can write the conditional density as
$$ Y\mid X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(p(X); n) $$
and this makes it more clear that the random component is binomial conditional on $X$.
